# Specify HTTP Request Headers in x-amazon-apigateway-integration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-api-gateway

In API Gateway, you can specify, under a method's Method Request setting, HTTP Request Headers to forward along. I currently set a required name of Authorization as part of the Swagger specification document I import via put_rest_api API Gateway client. This gets imported into API Gateway just fine, as shown here.

[image]

```
parameters: [{
  "in": "header",
  "name": "Authorization",
  "type": "string",
  "required": true
}]
```

But I also need to set it a HTTP Header mapping via the method's Integration Request

[image]

Is there a way to specify this when using the `x-amazon-apigateway-integration` object of a Swagger specification document? I've tried something like the following but I get an error message.

```
requestParameters: {
  "integration.request.header.authorization" => "method.request.header.authorization"
}
```

```
errors : [Invalid mapping expression parameter specified: method.request.header.authorization]
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the name is case sensitive. Changing it to match the name of the parameters object allows it to import and be set within API Gateway.

`"integration.request.header.Authorization": "method.request.header.Authorization"`